# Dumping Database with PROUTIL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

Is there a way to dump the whole database? I've tried using this PROUTIL command, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
PROUTIL db1 -C DUMP "C:\var".
```

Comment: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmadm%2Fproutil-dump-qualifier.html -- the first argument after "-C dump" is the table name, the second  argument is the directory to put the data in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There is no version of a proutil command that dumps the entire database in a single command.

You need to create a script to dump each table individually.  One (simplistic) way to do that is something like this:

```
output to value(  "dumpall.sh" ).
for each _file no-lock where _tbl-type = "t":
  put unformatted "_proutil " pdbname(1) " -C dump " _file-name " ." skip.
end. 
output close.
```

(The Progress meta schema refers to tables as "files" because SQL nomenclature had not quite taken over the world in the early 80s. _tbl-type was introduced much later.  Type "t" is an ordinary application table, "v" is a virtual table, and "s" is a system table.  You don't want to dump "v" or "s" and proutil won't dump them anyway.)

Dumping (and re-loading) a small demo database in this manner is pretty straight-forward.  There are, however, a lot of possible improvements to this approach if you are working with a more substantial db (like a 100GB production database).  There are also many things other than the raw table data involved.  The specifics vary by application (not everyone uses every feature of the db) but it is also very common to need to dump & reload sequence values, users, and SQL permissions to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

There are many links describing how to do this.

[Using ABL Code](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P124532)
[Using Data Dictionary/Data Administration](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/15884)